# Tracert throws up an error with -R option

Tags: traceroute

When I use tracert without any options, it runs fine. As in:

> tracert google.com

But when I run it with -R:

> tracert -R google.com

It throws up the error "Unable to resolve target system name google.com". Why does this happen? how is it able to resolve the address in the first case, but not the second?

How do I fix this?

Comment: `-R` Trace round-trip path (**IPv6-only**). Is your network set up to use IPv6?

Comment: No. That explains it. Thank you!

Comment: On an another note, why do you think tracert without "-R" is set up to work with or without IPv6, but not with -R? And how do I do a roundtrip check with IPv4 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `Tracert` throws up an error with -R option

```
F:\test>tracert /?

Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops] [-j host-list] [-w timeout]
               [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:
    -d                 Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
    -h maximum_hops    Maximum number of hops to search for target.
    -j host-list       Loose source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -w timeout         Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
    -R                 Trace round-trip path (IPv6-only).
    -S srcaddr         Source address to use (IPv6-only).
    -4                 Force using IPv4.
    -6                 Force using IPv6.
```

`-R` is **Trace round-trip path (IPv6-only)**, so this option will only work if the network is set up to use IPv6.

> And how do I do a round trip check with IPv4 only?

You can't as only IPv6 has the extension header required

> `/R` Specifies that the **IPv6 Routing extension header** be used to send an echo Request message to the local host, using the destination as an intermediate destination and testing the reverse route.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [tracert | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tracert)